# Overview of steps necessary to make application ICS-compatible?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to make some of my applications available on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) devices.  It would be helpful to know the different things to look for, as sort of a checklist.

What are the generic steps necessary to make an application available and functional on an Ice Cream Sandwich device?  I'm not looking for every single potential API change to make, but any detail would be appreciated.

Comment: None :-) Just run up a 4.0 emulator an QA it. what does your app do?

Comment: One of the apps does a lot of things... Bluetooth connection, Maps+location, SQLite database, graphics drawing, gestures... I guess this might be a poor question though if everything is already meant to be compatible with ICS.  I guess I'm asking if there are some things to watch out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I have encountered relating to usability is that if you have a fullscreen activity, to allow some way to exit it or go back since phones might not have hardware keys to send the back event. Basically, never assume that the user has hardware keys available.

Google also recently released a design guide for ICS available at http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, as Blundell said, it should work without any problems. I have however, found one quirk while running ICS in the emulator with my apps (maybe this applied to Honeycomb as well, no idea).

Here it is - if you have an app widget, and you don't provide the *android:previewImage* attribute in the *appwidget-provider* configuration, your widget will **not** be visible in the "Widgets" tab. You can use an app that comes with the ICS emulator (Widget Preview) to generate this preview image.

Comment: Are you sure that it will not be visible? The documentation says "If not supplied, the AppWidget's icon will be used.".

Comment: Well, yeah, I've seen that bit too... after I couldn't find my widget, and started researching the problem :). The widget was generally recognized by the system (it was available in the aforementioned Widget Preview). The only thing I changed was that configuration value.

Like I said, I only verified this on the ICS emulator (so it could be an emulator bug, like the 2.3 reorientation problem). Android is a great OS, but every system has bugs.

Comment: The preview image is not required. You just need to set the target SDK Version to 14 to make the widgets visible.